# Cube wont destroy on collision in unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collision-detection

I'm making a game where the player is flying a plane(full rigidbody, colliders) and I have a cube with the following script attached:

```
 using UnityEngine;
 using System.Collections;

 public class collision : MonoBehaviour
 {
     void OnCollisionEnter(Collision col)
     {
         if (col.gameObject.name == "breakableBox")
         {
             Destroy(col.gameObject);
         }
     }
 }
```

And what I'm trying to make happen is that once the plane crashes into the cube, the cube disappears. Instead, the plane just bounces off the cube, which is really strange. Basically the cube acts like a concrete box and it doesn't move or get destroyed. How can I fix that?

Comment: On the cube's collider component, maybe check isTrigger?

Comment: make sure the object's *name* is `breakableBox` and not its tag. Although you should be using tags for this instead of name, that way you could have more than just one.

Comment: you should be attaching this script to the plane, not the box.

Answer (score 1):

If this script is attached to the cube it won't work.

The `void OnCollisionEnter(Collision col)` functions is receiving the collision object of your player so it's checking if the player has the name "breakableBox" and trying to destroy it.

I think that if you attach this script to your player OR change it to something like this:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class collision : MonoBehaviour
{
    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision col)
    {
        if (col.gameObject.name == <player_Name>)
        {
            Destroy(this.gameObject);
        }
    }
}
```

You can make it work.

Comment: renaming the `Collider` parameter to `other` helps realize what's going on too.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the collider of the box as "Trigger" and use this:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

 public class collision : MonoBehaviour
 {
     void OnTriggerEnter(Collider col)
     {
         if (col.gameObject.name == "breakableBox")
         {
             Destroy(col.gameObject);
         }
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well There is so many factor about that. Try some of these options :

1. First check the collided object. It must have "breakableBox" name.
2. OnCollisionEnter(Collision col) works if the trigger not checked and
       OnTriggerEnter(Collider col) works if the trigger is checked.
3. Make sure you're moving the object not using transform, but using rigidbody.velocity.
4. Try to Debug.Log outside if function. If the logs is showing, then the
   validation is wrong.

Only these that comes from my mind. Hope it help